# What can/should we use chat for?

Tags: discussion, chat

I noticed that chat is up now.  What can/should it be used for? I like the idea of real-time communication but can't think of an appropriate use case for it.

-M

Answer (score 3):

Well, we're using chat for:

- Project Update Thursday
- Blog discussions
- General chat

If anyone has any other ideas just raise them in chat or even create a room and publicise them here.