# website for discussing home improvement design ideas

Tags: design

We are in the process of renovating our newly bought apartment and have many doubts on how to design the kitchen. We have had an architect draw a couple of ideas and have made some 3d drawings in floorplanner ourselves. But we are still not really satisfied... We are running low on time now that the constructors have started tearing down the walls etc.

Anyone knows if there exists a site where one can upload a project (with drawing, description, photos etc.) where people could contribute with ideas, could be on a pay-per-idea basis.

Answer (score 2):

Posting it here in the form of a question like "What are some suggestions for a kitchen layout for my house?" seems reasonable to me.

In the question details, you should have:

- The floorplan, with dimensions, which should show doors, windows, and existing electrical, gas, water hookups
- Any models you've already done that are relevant
- Your specific goals:

  - If the kitchen is supposed to be just a place to cook, or a place to socialize - eg, including an island and/or spots to seat x number of people at the island/counter
  - If you want special items like wine coolers, over-the-range microwave
  - Want as much storage space as possible, or prefer open areas
- Any existing cabinets/appliances/features you want to make use of
- If you are trying to minimize movement of plumbing/electrical, or if there is anything that specifically cannot move

Obviously, you can also ask much more specific questions, and providing a subset of the above data would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, I have posted the question here:http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4347/suggestions-for-a-kitchen-layout-for-my-house

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is use for our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111) - see [this meta question](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/212/194) - however the traffic is **very** low on that so you might not get a timely response.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask specific questions here. I've historically found the Taunton Fine Homebuilding magazine's forums full of very competent tradesfolks who offer advice.